# Cloud function get oauth2 token python api

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I am having trouble sending an authenticated firestore REST API request from a cloud function. The request needs to have an oauth2 token in the header. I've followed the docs here https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating and tried the python function they provided, but that still does not give the right authentication. What has worked so far is copying the token from `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` but that expires after an hour. Any ideas?

```
import urllib
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token


def make_authorized_get_request(endpoint, audience):
    """
    make_authorized_get_request makes a GET request to the specified HTTP endpoint
    by authenticating with the ID token obtained from the google-auth client library
    using the specified audience value.
    """

    # Cloud Functions uses your function's URL as the `audience` value
    # audience = https://project-region-projectid.cloudfunctions.net/myFunction
    # For Cloud Functions, `endpoint` and `audience` should be equal

    req = urllib.request.Request(endpoint)

    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, audience)

    req.add_header("Authorization", f"Bearer {id_token}")
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    return response.read()
```

The above function results in a`urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized"`

Comment: The error suggests that you've not (correctly followed the instructions) granted the Service Account that you're using to invoke the request to the Cloud Function with `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker`. Using `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` should not work because that is an access token and to invoke the Cloud Function you'll need an id token.

Comment: @DazWilkin I am trying to make the request from a cloud function, not to a cloud function. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Aha, yes that would make sense (explaining why `gcloud auth` works). I assume the receiving service is another Google service. Generally, you would use the relevant service's library to simplify auth (among other things).

Comment: The command `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` generates an OAuth Access Token. The code you are using generates an OIDC Identity Token. Very different tokens used for different types of authorization. Edit your question with more details. Note: the default max expiration is 3,600 seconds. After that time you must request a new token. That limit is raised to 12 hours for organizations. `constraints/iam.allowServiceAccountCredentialLifetimeExtension` https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints

Comment: Thank you for replies. The solution in my case was to add "Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin" role to the service account that would generate the token.

Comment: Can you post your solution as answer? So that, it will help others who are facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in my case was to add datastore.importExportAdmin "Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin" role to the service account that would generate the token. And to use the code below to generate a token from credentials:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
```

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam#roles

Comment: Either the details in your question are incorrect or your answer is. Adding an IAM role to a service account (IAM member) does not affect Identity Tokens, it does affect Access Tokens. The code in your question creates OIDC Identity Tokens.

Comment: Updated details in answer